# Output repeating a line

Tags: java, hashmap, output

In my output, it keeps repeating a line and then squishing it together in the next line. I want to know to rid myself of it

**OUTPUT**

```
Rick Grimes
Rick Grimes rescued Carl 100pts!

Rick Grimes rescued Michone 50pts!
Rick Grimes rescued Michone 50pts!

Characters rescued: Carl, Michone Total points: 150
```

As you can see, `line 3` adds the previous rescue in front of the next one

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Rick Grimes
Rick Grimes rescued Carl 100pts!

Rick Grimes rescued Michone 50pts!

Characters rescued: Carl, Michone Total points: 150
```

Here is my code

**GameDriver.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

         Hero N = new Cop();
         String s;
         File f = new File (args[0]);
         Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
         while (input.hasNext()) {
                s = input.next();
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("h")) {
                                        System.out.println(N.getHeroName());
                                       }

                if (s.startsWith("r")) {
                                        String p = input.next();
                                        String a = input.next();
                                        String cn = input.next();
                                        int pts = input.nextInt();
                                        N.newMap.put(cn, pts);
                                        System.out.println(N.rescue(cn));

                                       }

                if (s.startsWith("v")) {
                                        System.out.println(N.view());
                                       }
         }

  }
}
```

**Hero.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public abstract class Hero extends Character
{
   private String heroname1;
   public Hero() {
          heroname1 = "Rick Grimes"; //the default player name
   }
   HashMap<String, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

   public Hero(String newhero) {
          if (newhero.length() > 0) {
               heroname1 = newhero;
          } else { heroname1 = "Rick Grimes"; } //defaulted as protagonist
   }

   public String getHeroName() {
          return heroname1; //return the name
   }

   public String rescue(String key) { //class to rescue people or things
          String out = "";
          for(String _key : newMap.keySet()) {
              out += heroname1 + " rescued " + key + " " + newMap.get(key) + "pts!" + "\n";
          }
          return out;
   }

   public String toString() { //print
          return heroname1;

   }
   public String view() {
          Set<String> names = newMap.keySet();
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Characters rescued: ");
          int i = 0;
          for (String name : names) {
              if (i == 0) {
                  sb.append(name);
                  i++;
              } else {
                  sb.append(", ");
                  sb.append(name);
              }
          }

          String printNames = sb.toString();
          Collection<Integer> points = newMap.values();
          StringBuilder sp = new StringBuilder("Total points: ");
          int sum = 0;
          for (Integer value : points) {
               sum += value;
          }
          sp.append(sum);
          String printPoints = sp.toString();
          return printNames + " " + printPoints ;
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please ask for any clarification! **THANKS!!**

**EDIT here is my .txt file**

```
c h Rick Grimes
r Rick Grimes Carl 100
r Rick Grimes Michonne 50
v Rick Grimes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your println into view.

```
  if (s.startsWith("r")) {
            String p = input.next();
            String a = input.next();
            String cn = input.next();
            int pts = input.nextInt();
            N.newMap.put(cn, pts);
            System.out.println(N.rescue());

                       }

if (s.startsWith("v")) {
                        System.out.println(N.view());
                       }
```

Change it to.

```
 if (s.startsWith("r")) {
    String p = input.next();
    String a = input.next();
    String cn = input.next();
    int pts = input.nextInt();
    N.newMap.put(cn, pts);


   }

   if (s.startsWith("v")) {
    System.out.println(N.rescue());
    System.out.println(N.view());
   }
```

Since your iterating all values.

```
 public String rescue() { 
          String out = "";
          for(String _key : newMap.keySet()) {
              out += heroname1 + " rescued " + _key + " " + newMap.get(_key) + "!\n"
          }
          return out;
   }
```

**EDIT**
Or remove the loop if you want to print it on 'r'.

```
 public String rescue(String key) {
          String out = "";
          out = heroname1 + " rescued " + key + " " + newMap.get(key) + "pts!" + "\n";
          return out;
   }
```

Also used add "\n" like what @almas shaikh said

Comment: While this works, the tester (who is not me) will use the `r` command and not the `v` command and expect an output for rescuing, `v` is supposed to show the status of the current player

Answer (score 3):

You are appending the output of first with next one in line here:

```
out += heroname1 + " rescued " + _key + " " + newMap.get(_key);
```

You should either return array of Strings or you should add a new line something like:

```
out += heroname1 + " rescued " + _key + " " + newMap.get(_key) + "\n";
```

Comment: isn't `\n` `C++` though?

Comment: so for java `System.out.println()` instead?

Comment: @Junikin - The thing is, you are appending in a loop. So, you need to add a newline character (`\n`). Also, `String out = "".toString();` should be changed to `String out = "";` .

Comment: while this solves the combining thing, I still don't want the first rescue popping up again, please look at my Desired output, any ideas?

Comment: You need to pass on the System.out.println(N.rescue(cn)); and in Hero class, you should change rescue method as `public String rescue(String key) { return heroname1 + " rescued " + key + " " + newMap.get(key); }`

Comment: Ok we are close, I will update my newest code and output